# Returning selective Data from mongodb as specified in Flask

Tags: python, web-services, mongodb, pymongo

i have a webservice that takes data from mongodb and returns it over a local web service.
I want to implement a query based control over here that would allow filtering the webservice data from a GUI.

Currently my html file is using the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<body>
    <h1>Welcome to App</h1>
    <h2>Enter your username</h2>
    <form action="." method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="text">
        <input type="submit" name="my-form" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my app.py which is running on flask looks like:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import render_template
from flask import request
from pymongo import Connection
import json
from bson import json_util
from bson.json_util import dumps

app = Flask(__name__)

MONGODB_HOST = '172.16.1.95'
MONGODB_PORT = 27017
DBS_NAME = 'AllTables'
COLLECTION_NAME = 'SubjectViews'


@app.route('/')
def my_form():
    return render_template("index.html")



@app.route('/testtag', methods=['POST'])
def my_form():
    text = request.form['text']
    processed_text = " + text + "
    return processed_text
    def donorschoose_projects():
        connection = Connection(MONGODB_HOST, MONGODB_PORT)
        collection = connection[DBS_NAME][COLLECTION_NAME]
        projects = collection.find({"tags":"processed_text"})
        json_projects = []
        for project in projects:
            json_projects.append(project)
        json_projects = json.dumps(json_projects, default=json_util.default)
        connection.disconnect()
        return json_projects

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5001,debug=True)
```

What i am trying to do is to get a input from the user in index.html, pass it into the collection.find parameter in app.py so that on my webservice URL i will get data filtered for that particular user. Unfortunately i am running into errors. 
Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you,
Anmol

EDIT: No luck so far!

Comment: "i am running into errors." what errors are you running into? consider reading this: http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html then update your question with the information we need to answer you effectively

Comment: File "app.py", line 23, in <module>
  @app.route('/testtag', methods=['POST'])
File "C:\projects\myprojectvenv\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 101
3, in decorator
    self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, **options)
  File "C:\projects\myprojectvenv\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 62,
 in wrapper_func
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\projects\myprojectvenv\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 984
, in add_url_rule
    'existing endpoint function: %s' % endpoint)
AssertionError: View function mapping is overwriting an existing endpoint functi
on: my_form

Comment: Jesse,
also, My basic question was not about error trouble shooting. It was how to capture the user input on index.html into my app.py file. If you refer to the code in the question, i want to capture the user input as a variable and then search the mongo db tags based on the captured variable. Essentially implementing a row level access mechanism. I hope i am explaining clearly :) thank you